# auto-increment badges number when receiving push notifications from APNS

Tags: php, iphone, ios, push-notification, badge

I would like to let the badge number increasing automatically when receiving push notifications, for example: if I receive two notifications let the number displays as 2, if I receive more, the number increases. And I want to let the number returns zero when I open the application. So what I am doing is the following:
the code in application did finish launching

`[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;`

otherwise, the code in did Receive Remote Notification is

`application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"] integerValue];`

In the server, in the php file:

```
$payload = '{"aps": {"alert":"'.$message.'", "sound":"default","badge":"+1"}}';
```

But, unfortunately, the number doesn't incremented, please correct me if the code above is wrong, thank you per advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is not option in push notifications to auto-increment the badges number. You will have to pass the number that will be shown on the badge.

Also the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` will only be called if the app is running foreground. Here you could calculate the new badge number, but this will not help you if you app is not in the foreground.

You will need to track the badge number server side as well.

Comment: yes I know there is no option, that is what I am asking? how can I do it, can u tell me how can I track the badge number server side ? please

Comment: You will have to make API calls for your web-service, which the app can call. How to do this is up to you and the way you have setup your database. Your app will need to tell you server which messages it has read and you will need to count the number of unread message for the user.

Comment: @Fatima since we have no idea of how you database is set up nor how the data that is in there we can not solve the issue for you. I can write a lot of code for you to solve the problem but then you will ask me how to integrate it with your system. Also we are here to help but not write code for you.

Comment: @rckoenes How i can track the badge number at server side.

Comment: @railsbox, in a database.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like following

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:    (NSDictionary *)userInfo {

NSLog(@"userInfo:%@",userInfo);

    badge_value+=[[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"badge"]intValue];<br>
    NSLog(@"Totoal badge Value:%d",badge_value);<br>

for (id key in userInfo) {
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
}
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = badge_value;}
```

Comment: thank you, I will try it by Monday, then give you a feedback.

Comment: what shall I put instead of +1 in this query :`$payload = '{"aps": {"alert":"'.$message.'", "sound":"default","badge":"+1"}}';`

Comment: no need to increment badge in php code.you need to increment badge when norification is recieved and clear badge when it is read. manage badge at ios side.

Comment: @wasim, In many places its given "iOS device does not increment the badge counter automatically each time a new push message is received. To manage badge counter you need to send push notification with proper badge value." If I send correct badge count in payload, then how  does server know number of unread messages in app?